# Storing indices of unique strings/elements of a vector in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, vector, unique

I have three vectors A, B and C of same size. A and B are numeric quantities while C is a cell array of strings. I want to generate sub-vectors of A based on the unique values of B and C. For example, let

```
A = [0.45 0.89 0.12 0.35 0.40 0.93 0.12 0.35 0.72 0.59];
B = [1 1 3 1 8 1 8 8 1 1];
C = [{'Tom'}, {'Mary'}, {'Dick'}, {'Harry'}, {'Dick'}, {'Tom'}, {'Tom'}, {'Mary'}, {'Tom'}, {'Mary'}];
```

So, I first tried to find the unique values of B and C using MATLAB's unique function. The results are as follows:

```
unique(B)
ans =
 1    3     8
unique(C)
ans = 
'Dick'    'Harry'    'Mary'    'Tom'
```

Now, I want to arrange the vector A by the unique values in B and C. Suppose the indices of the unique values of the first element of unique(B) are 
[row_b1, colb1], second element indices be [row_b2, colb2] and so on. Then, based on the unique values in B, I would like to generate the following three vectors:

```
A_B1 = A(rowb1, colb1);
A_B2 = A(rowb2, colb2);
A_B3 = A(rowb3, colb3);
```

Similarly, based on the unique values of C, I would like to generate following vectors:

```
A_C1 = A(rowc1, colc1);
A_C2 = A(rowc2, colc2);
A_C3 = A(rowc3, colc3);
A_C4 = A(rowc4, colc4);
```

However, I didn't find anything in the unique command that tells me the indices of the unique values in the vector i.e. row_b1, col_b1, ... etc. Could someone please point out how to obtain these indices? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Edit1: I should mention that I posted a general case. But in my problem A, B and C are matrices. I figured if I could solve this for a vector, then it should be a similar extension for a matrix.

Edit2: Here are the answers I am expecting:

```
A_B1 = [0.45 0.89 0.35 0.93 0.72 0.59]
A_B2 = [0.12]
A_B3 = [0.40 0.12 0.35]
```

and

```
A_C1 = [0.45 0.93 0.12 0.72]
A_C2 = [0.89 0.35 0.59]
A_C3 = [0.12 0.40]
A_C4 = [0.35]
```

Comment: `A` is a vector but you are indexing it like a matrix `A(rowb1, colb1)`. You seem to work with vectors, when you refer to `row_b1` and `colb1`, row and column of what matrix you are referring to?

Comment: Did any of the answers work for you?

Comment: Hi Mohsen, please see my edit. I posted a case for vector. But in my problem A, B and C could be matrices.

Comment: Hi brodroll. No, please see my further comments and edits on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the extra outputs of the *unique* function in your favor:

```
[ub ib jb]=unique(B);
```

Where *ub*,*ib* and *jb* are defined as:

- ub = unique(B);
- B(ib) = ub;
- ub(jb) = B;

Which you can use to get your A_B values:

```
A_B=A(ib);
```

The same logic applies to C:

```
[cu ic jc]=unique(C);
A_C=A(ic);
```

Since A, B and C are vectors of the same size.

**EDIT**

Since (rowb1,colb1), (rowb2,colb2) and (rowb3,colb3) are just placeholders as explained in the comments, what you really want is the indexes where each unique value appears and use these indexes to get your A values. To get the position where each unique value appears  you can use:

```
>> idxA_B=bsxfun(@eq,B,unique(B)')

ans =

     1     1     0     1     0     1     0     0     1     1
     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     1     0     1     1     0     0
```

So your A_B values are given by:

```
A_B1=A(idxA_B(1,:));
A_B2=A(idxA_B(2,:));
A_B3=A(idxA_B(3,:));
```

The same logic applies to C. But as @Parag S. Chandakkar pointed out, @eq does not work with strings so you need to get your C indexes the following way:

```
aux=cellfun(@(x) strcmp(x,unique(C)'),C,'UniformOutput',false);
idxA_C = [aux{:}];
A_C1=A(idxA_C(1,:));
A_C2=A(idxA_C(2,:));
A_C3=A(idxA_C(3,:));
A_C4=A(idxA_C(4,:));
```

Comment: Hi Brodroll, thanks. But this is not what I am looking for. For example, let us consider the data set I mentioned. If I follow the command sequence in your reply, I get:

Comment: Hi Brodroll, thanks. But this is not what I am looking for. For example, let us consider the data set I mentioned. If I follow the command sequence `code` [ub jb ib] = unique(B); A_B = A(ib); `code`, this gives A_B = [0.4500    0.1200    0.4000]. But what I want is as follows: A_B1 = [0.45 0.89 0.35 0.93 0.72 0.59], A_B2 = [0.12], and A_B3 = [0.40 0.12 0.35].

Comment: I don't quite understand your indexing rule. In the end what you have is: A_B1=A([1 2 4 5 9 10]); A_B2=A([3]); A_B3=A([5 7 8]) . In your example you state that A_B1=A(rowb1,colb1), which can be only a single value, not a vector the way I see.

Comment: Hi Brodroll, I see that my indexing scheme might have caused some confusion. I meant rowb1, colb1 to be just placeholders for "every" index where B has a unique value B1. So, [rowb1, colb1] correspond to multiple pairs of indices.

Comment: @roalddahl14 That makes much more sense. THanks for clearing things up. See my following edit

Comment: Thanks brodroll. This indeed works with the vector B which is numeric, but not with the string vector C.

Comment: You just need to use strcmp as @Parag suggested, I'll edit for completion's sake

Answer (score 1):

Lets consider the same example.

```
A = [0.45 0.89 0.12 0.35 0.40 0.93 0.12 0.35 0.72 0.59];
B = [1 1 3 1 8 1 8 8 1 1];
C = [{'Tom'}, {'Mary'}, {'Dick'}, {'Harry'}, {'Dick'}, {'Tom'}, {'Tom'}, {'Mary'}, {'Tom'}, {'Mary'}];

[uniqueB,indB,~]=unique(B);
[uniqueC,indC,~]=unique(C);
A_indB=A(indB); //This and the following line is what you want, I think.
A_indC=A(indC);
```

This is given in the documentation for [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html).

## Edit:

This is how I would do it for matrices (numeric as well as character).

First generate some matrices.

```
A1=[A;A(randperm(length(A)));A(randperm(length(A)))];
B1=[B;B(randperm(length(B)));B(randperm(length(B)))];
C1=[C;C(randperm(length(C)));C(randperm(length(C)))];
```

Now,

```
indB=arrayfun(@(x) bsxfun(@eq,B1,x),unique(B1),'uni',0);
indC=arrayfun(@(x) strcmp(C1,x),unique(C1),'uni',0); % above line only works 
                                                     % for numeric arrays
```

and get the answer as,

```
A_B1=A(indB{1,1});
A_B2=A(indB{2,1});
A_C1=A(indC{1,1});
A_C2=A(indC{2,1}); % and so on
```

Comment: Hi Parag, thanks. please see my edits and comments. Following your command sequence gives a different result than what I want.

Comment: @roalddahl14 I think now my solution should work as you had desired.

Comment: Thanks Parag! This solved my problem. It works for both numeric and string matrices!

Comment: @roalddahl14 Please accept the answer by clicking the checkmark on the right. That removes the question from the unanswered list.